# Can Hegel's dialectical history be interpreted as a way to look positively at life?

Tags: hegel, philosophy-of-history

Hegel's dialectic method of interpreting history says that events occur in the following steps: a) an event happens b) an opposing event comes to contradict the original event c) a third event takes the first two and synthesis between the two.

As far as I know, this is the general way in which Hegel looks at history. From there he goes to take a rather mystical approach to history, saying that through it the "world spirit" is "showing itself" (not sure about the exact phrasing he uses).

Could we instead of going the more mystic path, interpret Hegel's history of philosophy as a way to look at life? For example, something like: an event happens to me, but then a worse event happens, but I should know that in the end a third event would happen that'd synthesis between the two (I'd must admit that's how I look at life most of the time).

Comment: See [Hegel's Dialectics](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/hegel-dialectics/) and [Hegel's philosophy of history](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/history/#HegHis).

Comment: Hegel's [The Phenomenology of Spirit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Phenomenology_of_Spirit#Consciousness) already deal of consciousness and self-consciousness.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to show here - that the way I interpret Hegel in the question is the common interpretation?

Comment: Hegel's theory in the *Phenomenology* is about the "I", consciousness and freedom: not about "everyday life".

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA so, what exactly is the issue with my question? I'm asking if it can be interpreted (and perhaps incorporated) into that subject.

Comment: How this theory works out only you can decide after working with and studying it. I have put Luxemberg's Wikipedia here, we all know the negatives of Wikipedia, anyway. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosa_Luxemburg  Liebknect, Luxemburg, and Kurt Eisner (an organizing genius)  ended up dead, murdered, along with many others. Why, since Marxism was reasonable?  Ah!  The superego, the authoritarian personality, then the interest in Freud-and the genesis of the Frankfurt School.

Comment: @Gordon so, with taking Hegel's philosophy of history in the micro level rather than the macro, State, Spirit of the World level, we can interpret it as I've presented, right?

Comment: @Gordon OK thanks, I'll get those 3 years eventually. In the meantime, any online class videos you know of that I can watch? (unless the Bernstein reference is exactly that)

Comment: My first answer was too negative. I would not want to discourage anyone from studying Hegel. There is a lot of material on the internet. Like the Bernstein "tapes", it includes the professor's syllabus for his class, with suggested readings. http://www.bernsteintapes.com/ Now surely, some other professor will disagree with Bernstein!  There is also W.T. Stace's philosophy of Hegel at Internet Archive.

Comment: I removed the link to Spark notes regarding Hegel's introductory lectures to his philosophy of history because there was too many ads, but I think it's worth reading. The link to Lenin I also took down because I see there is already a link to information on Hegel's dialectic, but I will say that Lenin's interpretations are worth reading as regards Hegel. The  Wikipedia regarding Luxemburg et.al. I leave because the characters all knew the philosophy of Hegel and Marx, and this was a very unique moment in history.  Though Hegel "looked back", what had he started?  How did it develop?  Etc.

Answer (score 2):

The thesis-antithesis-synthesis idea is definitely present in Hegel but it was Engels who imposed this formula on the interpretation of Hegel as the major key to his entire philosophy.

M. Allegranza is, of course, completely right that Hegel's philosophy operates above the level of everyday life. Hegel's view of history, to which you draw attention is, very roughly that human history exemplifies through different civilisations at different times progressively deeper understandings and embodiments of freedom. That's the view, shorn of all detail, subtlety and illustration.

Hegel himself doesn't think there is any mysticism in his philosophy of history. The progressive realisation of freedom is also a rational process. The Hegelian relation between freedom and reason is too involved to go into here.

Reading your question sympathetically, I think I can see your point. Regardless of how Hegel on a grand philosophical level used the ideas of thesis-antithesis-synthesis, could you use them illuminatingly to interpret your own 'everyday life' ? Quick answer : I can't see why not. If it works, use it ! A sound pragmatic attitude.

Answer (score 2):

You could, but it only is a "positive" outlook if you make one major assumption: One of the two events has to be positive from your point of view.

Hegel only says that to each event a conflicting event will arise, which eventually will lead to a synthesizing event that lies somewhere between the first two events. The conflict between the first two events doesn't have to align with anything that would make you see one of the events as better or worse.

Furthermore, look at this case:
Something bad happens to you, then something even worse happens, in the end the synthesis lies somewhere between bad and worse.
Now a fourth event happens that is even worse. The new synthesis lies somwhere between this event and the second one.
The synthesis provides a temporary relief, but doesn't prevent a constant downward movement.

The outlook towards life you describe, requires that you allready assume a sort of "golden mean" towards which events will return, which is to say, you allready have the conclusion you want to arive at, why do you need any form of philosophy to justify it?

Comment: "the synthesis provides a temporary relief, but doesn't prevent a constant downward movement" - of course, but isn't that temporary relief what keeps us on our feet in life? We could expect a worse event to happen, but we take our comfort in the relief passages.

Comment: Not really, remember, the "relief" I'm talking about in this scenario is only a return to a still bad state, not the return to a good or neutral state. Imagine the following sentence: "They stopped stabbing me for a moment, and returned to beating me with clubs, while they had their knifes sharpened." A relief is only a good thing when it's combined with hope, which you can't get just by applying Hegel.

Comment: I understand you know, and I think it's interesting to come up here with a distinction between hope and false hope - when we're presented with the scenario you suggested, we come to the conclusion the hope that was thought was actually false hope. I like what we did here.

Comment: Actually now that I think about it, I can go around what you're saying with positivistic hope, the same Hegel uses for freedom - I can always look at the whole scenario you've presented as a whole, an entire event, and not thesis-antithesis-synthesis I analyze. Rather, I'll take a wider look, a wide enough look that'll give me the positive outcome. This could be of course criticized as not scientifically honorable, but it's basically what Hegel did.